# Android MenuProvider not working inside Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I need to add a menu depending on the fragment the user is looking at.

I tried to use the new `MenuProvider` in the `onViewCreated`-Method of my Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()

    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't do anything with my Toolbar in the Main-activity. Do I have to enable menus somewhere?

**Edit 1**
As I saw in an answer to a similar problem, putting this into my MainActivity didn't do the trick:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

**Edit 2**
Moving my menu item into a group didn't fix it either.

**Edit 3**
I put a breakpoint at `menuInflater.inflate()` but it wasn't activated, which tells me, the activity does not care about the menu provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a `setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))` in the `onCreate` of my MainActivity